# Regarding the Blue Card Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas, blue-card, pr

I am a Blue card holder, paying Social security/unemployment insurance since May 2020; my Blue card was issued mid-September 2020. I applied for unemployment benefit 1. The unemployment office asked me to get a letter that I could work anywhere and only the unemployment benefit. We can work anywhere in Blue card after 2 years; the immigration provided the letter from mid-September, not May. Due to this, I lost some amount.

Did you face any similar experiences with the unemployment office?

For many of us, there is a gap between the date of joining(employement) and the date of issue on the Blue card; how to solve that?

Comment: Your payslips determine the eligablity for the unemployment benifits, not the card. The 2 years starts in May. Your Blue-Card was granted with the D-Visa, not when the physical card was issued. The last part of sentance 3 is not clear.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thanks. I have edited the last line; the employer's name was mentioned in the work permit. First, the unemployment office asked me to change it so I could work anywhere. I asked the immigration office, and they wrote the date 11.09.22(2 years from the date of issue(blue card)), and unemployment denied to provide unemployment benefits from 1.09.2021 to 10.09.2022. Now, question is back to my 3rd point